# DOM object - special characters will not shown correctly

Tags: php, dom

I have the following php code:

```
$html = '<table>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Date">übermittelt</td>
      <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Date">xD2</td>
      <td data-label="Location">xxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo $html; // NO PROBLEM WITH SPECIAL CHARACTERS 

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; // PROBLEM WITH SPECIAL CHARACTERS
```

My Problem is, that my last echo shows the result like this:

```
Ã¼bermittelt
```

The `echo $html` shows the result correctly like this:

```
übermittelt
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have the issue with this exact code or it's been redacted to share here? I can't figure out how DOMDocument could produce by itself what appear to be JavaScript entities, plus when I run it I only get `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object` because the source HTML doesn't seem to have tables at all.

Comment: I have updated my first post and put some html code into $html.
With this code I get the issue

Comment: And where/how does this have anything to do with cURL now …?

Comment: this is the test code. the $html variable will fill normally with dynamic html content. But now I guess the problem isn't cURL - it can be DOM

Comment: This is a character encoding problem; if the encoding isn’t indicated anywhere, most likely DOMDocument just guesses. Try explicitly forcing UTF-8, like this http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251

Comment: I tried this - but it doesn't works. I have modified my line like this. `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);`

Comment: As CBroe explains, DOMDocument doesn't really try to auto-detect the text encoding and your code sample does not contain any encoding information. Still, `\u00c3\u00bc` are **JavaScript** entities (also used in JSON)—nothing so far explains how they show up here since no JavaScript interpreter is involved.

Comment: I dont know why it doesn't work correctly :( But you can run my code live with this online simulator: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fea61e968e9c5cbee377842deeb96f3d09794b0a

Comment: Your online fiddle produces `Ã¼` not `\u00c3\u00bc`. Sure, the latter is the JavaScript encoding for the former, but they're still different strings from the both HTML and PHP perspectives. `Ã¼` is just mojibake for `ü` (I found [a table](https://github.com/dekellum/mojibake/blob/master/config/table.json)).

Comment: yes, the code shows a Ã¼, but it have to be "ü" - and thats the problem :/

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/90dd66ba53bcba4804149c87c6a3fda27ca2d49a - now what exactly about this is not working …?

Comment: Fine... The question has silently mutated once more and now the JavaScript entities are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your support:
solution was to defined this line correctly like this:

```
$dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $html);
```